# How to get Attribute using selector syntax in jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I need to get value of attribute `href` of `a` tag.
I know using `a.attr("href")` I can get href attribute value.

But I want to know is there any other way to get `href` attribute as like in `jTidy`
 (using syntax like `//a/@href`) for Jsoup.

Means can I use some selector syntax to get attribute directly ?

Thanks.

Comment: From [JSoup Selector class API docs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html): *"Class Selector -  CSS-like element selector, that finds **elements** matching a query."*. So the short answer is: **no** - you have to select the element(s) and get the attribute.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cant retrieve the attribute value by a single selector. Its purpose is to select elements by various criteria.

But you can select only those elements which have the attribute and then ask it's value.

```
Element withAttr = doc.select("a[href]").first();
String attrAvlue = withAttr.attr("href");
```

Comment: use `attr("abs:href")` for absolute url.